# How do I define an out-of-line class template member function with a non-trailing decltype return type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
template <class T>
struct foo {
    int x;
    decltype(x) f1();
};
```

It seems to be impossible to define `f1` out-of-line.  I have tried the following definitions, and none of them work:

```
template <class T> decltype(x) foo<T>::f1() {}
template <class T> auto foo<T>::f1() -> decltype(x) {}
template <class T> auto foo<T>::f1() { return x; }
template <class T> decltype(std::declval<foo<T>>().x) foo<T>::f1() {}
// This return type is copied from the gcc error message
template <class T> decltype (((foo<T>*)(void)0)->foo<T>::x) foo<T>::f1() {}
```

This isn't a problem in real code because changing the in-class declaration of `f1` to `auto f1() -> decltype(x);` allows the second definition. but I'm puzzled as to why that changes anything.  Is it even possible to declare the original `f1` out-of-line?

Comment: `decltype(T::x)`?

Comment: @PeteBecker I think you mean `decltype(foo<T>::x)` - which seems like it could work, but neither g++ nor clang++ like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dumb as this might seem, I believe the following is correct:

```
template <class T>
struct foo {
    int x;
    decltype(x) f1();
};

template <class T>
int foo<T>::f1() { return 0; }
```

Clang accepts it, but GCC doesn't, so I am going to say that I think GCC has a bug. [[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de51b5df3a5c7299)]

The issue is whether these two declarations of `f1` declare the same function (more technically, the same member function of the same class template). This is governed by [basic.link]/9, according to which:

> Two names that are the same (Clause 6) and that are declared in different scopes shall denote the same variable, function, type, template or namespace if
>
> - both names have external linkage or else both names have internal linkage and are declared in the same translation unit; and
> - both names refer to members of the same namespace or to members, not by inheritance, of the same class; and
> - when both names denote functions, the parameter-type-lists of the functions (11.3.5) are identical; and
> - when both names denote function templates, the signatures (17.5.6.1) are the same.

The requirements appear to be satisfied, provided that the return types are in fact the same (since the return type is part of the signature for a class member function template, according to [defns.signature.member.templ]). Since `foo<T>::x` is `int`, they are the same.

This would not be the case if the type of `x` were dependent. For example, GCC and Clang both reject the definition when the declaration of `x` is changed to `typename identity<T>::type x;`. [[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e27f386bdae0df7)] In that case, [temp.type]/2 would apply:

> If an expression *e* is type-dependent (17.6.2.2), `decltype(`*e*`)` denotes a unique dependent type. Two such
>   *decltype-specifiers* refer to the same type only if their *expression*s are equivalent (17.5.6.1). [ *Note:* However, such a type may be aliased, e.g., by a *typedef-name*. — *end note* ]

Perhaps GCC is in error for considering `x` to be type-dependent (it shouldn't be). However, this note suggests a workaround:

```
template <class T>
struct foo {
    int x;
    decltype(x) f1();
    using x_type = decltype(x);
};

template <class T>
typename foo<T>::x_type foo<T>::f1() { return 0; }
```

This works on both GCC and Clang. [[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc19cda216bf94e4)]

Answer (score 0):

(I cheated... sort of)

Using MSVC I clicked on "quick action -> create function declaration" for that member function and got this:

```
template<class T>
decltype(x) foo<T>::f1()
{
    return x;
}
```